# Does plugging iPhone into iTunes automatically update iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, software-update, software

If I plug an iPhone that's running an old version of iOS into a computer with iTunes, will iOS on the iPhone automatically update when the phone is plugged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your iPhone won't automatically update its software when connected to iTunes. You get an alert that your iPhone *can* be updated to newer version of iOS, but you can just close out of the window that the alert is in. Your iPhone may, however, automatically *sync with iTunes* when connected to your computer, but this can be disabled by unchecking a box in iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a notification to download and install it. You can opt out of this though.